# Python: VOXEL TO 3-D ARRAY

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, voxel

I'm new to Python and now trying to find a way to get a **3-d array include r,b,g colour from a voxel (.vox or .obj) file**. For example, it will return:

```
array=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0] #0,0,0 is r,b,g color
        [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]
        [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
       [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]
        [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]
        [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

Anyone who knows how to do **please teach me** :3

**IF PYTHON CAN'T, TELL ME ANY OTHER LANGUAGE WHICH CAN DO THAT (also how to do) PLEASE. I NEED IT NOW !**

Comment: How are you loading the voxel file into that array? Could you post an example or a Python session showing the steps?

Comment: Mention the file fortmat(extension). And do you want slice of voxel grid as output?

Comment: @LucasGodoy actually I'm looking for the way to do that. It's just an example which what I want the output array to be.

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde .vox and .obj file. If you can, please tell me both or just the vox one.

Comment: BTW, I also think of Axes3D. Is it possible to do what I want ??

Comment: I'm not familliar with `.vox` files, but `.obj` files don't actually contain any color info so you won't be able to "include any rgb info from it". The best you could do is get the geometry, for which I would recommend using https://www.patrickmin.com/binvox/ to voxelize your OBJ mesh. There is a python library to read `.binvox` files